# Why can't I jump to the result in Javadoc's search box?

Tags: java, javadoc

I use the JDK11 to generate the javadoc of apache commons-lang. When it finished, I open the index.html and input something in search box. The search box shows the results but when I click the result, there is nothing happened. I just want to jump to the result page. How can I generate a javadoc with the search function?

Comment: Did you check if JavaScript or popup is blocked in your browser?

Comment: Yes. My browser is chrome. I had checked the settings. The javascript is allowed to run.